# What is wrong with my simple meteor code

Tags: javascript, html, meteor

When I run it, nothing displays in the browser.
HTML:

```
<head>
<title>projectsiddharth</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello from india!</h1>
<div class="java">{{> timetemplate}}</div>
<template name="timetemplate">
<p>The time is now {{time}}</p>
</template>
</body>
```

JS:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
var data = {time: new Date()};
Template.timetemplate.helpers(data);
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {

}
```

Im new to meteor pls bear with me. This code is for displaying the time currently. Help appreciated, thanks

Comment: Hey, I don't use Meteor, but the examples on the Meteor Tutorial website show the template tags as being external to the body, not sure if that would affect your results. [Example](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/templates)

Comment: @AranDG haha my silly. its working now. Thank you so much bro :) my bad haha

Comment: @Siddarth Nay worries at all, I believe @K Ф posted this same solution as an answer below. I couldn't as I don't have meteor to test, ensure they get the rep mate as they no doubt debugged it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try by seperating your template from your body html.

```
<head>
 <title>projectsiddharth</title>
</head>
<body>
 <h1>Hello from india!</h1>
 <div class="java">{{> timetemplate}}</div>
</body>

<template name="timetemplate">
 <p>The time is now {{time}}</p>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are defining the Helpers the wrong way. Try:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Template.timetemplate.helpers({
        time: function(){
            return new Date();
        };
   });
}
```

Comment: I do not agree. I have a meteor project and I did time: Date() and was able to show the time with {{time}} in my template

Comment: Sir it says '=> Errors prevented startup:

   While processing files with ecmascript (for target web.b
   projectsiddharth.js:4:18: projectsiddharth.js: Unexpecte

   While processing files with ecmascript (for target os.wi
   projectsiddharth.js:4:18: projectsiddharth.js: Unexpecte

=> Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.'

Comment: @Siddarth Venu maybe this can help you solving this error https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/5551

Answer (score 0):

you forgot you libery of meteor.js, you should include it in your `head`

example is below

[codepen](http://codepen.io/motion_max/pen/jbgaQm)

Comment: Sir I have used Meteor before without including the Meteor js file. PS: I compile it in the command prompt so I dont need to include it.